# Rails 4, omniauth: create multiple authenticated users for UX testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, omniauth

My app allows users to interact with each other once they are authenticated using omniauth (linkedin, in my case). Perhaps I am overlooking a simple solution, but how do I create multiple users, which each have the ability to sign in/out, for UX testing? Is this where an Admin-type user comes in handy?

For example, I want to play around with different design/layout ideas for how responses to a given message are displayed. This requires at least two users, etc.

Comment: I would just use rails console to:

Make a second user(the first one would be you with your omniauth login)
Generate some messages from the fictive user
Then just test the layout

Comment: fair enough, it's probably not entirely necessary to have dummy users be able to sign in/out, but thought I'd ask. Thanks.